# как распаковать(импортировать) чужую программу на языке kotlin в IntelliJ Ideal?

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите, как распаковать(импортировать) чужую программу на языке kotlin в IntelliJ Ideal? Есть три архива (mobilepm-service, mobpm-app, mobpm-srv). И как потом запустить?

Answer (score 0):

чтоб импортировать программу в IntelliJ Idea необходимо распаковать архив, поместить в одну папку и открыть проект в IntelliJ Idea.